# Simulating a circuit diagram for action potential

Tags: biomaterials, structural-biology, membranes

[image: Neuronal Membrane as Cable Theory, from Wikimedia]

[Cable theory](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_theory) is a good simulation for the resting potential. It imagines patches of cell membrane lipid bilayer as capacitors and transmembrane ion channels as resistors.

But it seems this model is not enough to simulate the action potential cycle (Depolarisation, Repolarisation etc and associated Na+ and K+ channel states), and the propagation cycle of action potential. The array will seemingly produce a bland gradient of voltage along the circuit (as seen in 'length constant' graph)

**What would be a circuit diagram for a more working model of action potential cycle and its propagation?**

So far I have proceeded:

1. Zener diodes and/or voltage dependent resistors may help as simulate Na+ or K+ channels.
2. I may need to put some batteries at a certain interval along the circuit (serves as source of action potential)

Where I'm stuck:

**How can I simulate the "closing" or plugging off (inactivation) of the sodium channel?**

Comment: I think this needs more focus before answers start going in different directions. There's a possible neurobiology question here about simulation (primarily *in silico* though you could also talk about just the differential equations on paper) and a not-at-all-biology question about physically building an analog circuit to do this simulation. It sounds like you're mostly interested in the not-at-all-on-topic stuff.

Comment: @Bryan Krause I have edited the question to focus on one specific question.

Comment: Yes this is an in silico question. please migrate on appropriate site.

Comment: +1. Welcome to our new community and thank you for contributing your question here (even if not by choice!). We hope to see much more of you here in the future!!! But first, we have to answer your question! I've narrowed down your two questions into one, since we have a one question/post policy here: this had the effect of bumping your question back up to the top so that more people can see it, and will make it easier for people to answer it if they know the answer to question (1) but not (2). I've commented out the second question in case you want to ask it again later (maybe in a few weeks).

Comment: Have you considered the Hodgkin-Huxley model, or the Leaky-integrate-and-fire model, or the Moris-Lecar model or one of the many other ways to describe the action potential?

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.